# Notifications on an international site are inconsistent

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges, notifications, localization

The "You've earned the" text has been translated even though the badge was awarded on an English-speaking site.

[image]

Notice the +100, that has been translated, but that is because it refers to this site. On others it hasn't been translated - which is a little strange.

Comment: Those message are somewhat bind to an identifier and each site handles those identifiers according to the localization - I'm actually fine with the current behavior :)

Answer (score 3):

All* strings are translated relative to the site you're on. If you're on a localized site, it's not unreasonable to assume that you understand (some of) the language.

Note that the rest of the notifications are post titles - we do not automatically translate content anywhere, so these naturally appear in the language they were originally written in.

<sub><sup>*</sup> For some value of "all" - translations are ongoing as strings change and we try to catch up. A shoutout to the community managers and users on the localized sites who are helping out with the translations.</sub>

Comment: I'm a little confused why the +100 changes per site?

Comment: @Tim You get the 100 rep bonus on each site separately. Badge and privilege notifications are translated based on the site you're on when you view the achievement dropdown.

Comment: Okay, interesting way of doing it but that makes sense :) Thanks!